# file_get_contents PHP Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, php

when I try to get us file_get_contents to my weather, it shows me this error

What did I do wrong ??

Cant I just do:

```
<?php
function getWeather_PHP($location) {
  $l_location = (string)$location;
  $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?".$l_location."&lang=en&units=metric&appid=MY_API_KEY";
  $url = (string)$url;
  $contents = file_get_contents($url); //error occur here
  ...
  return weather_data;
?>
```

And in a script in same php file

```
<script>

    var inputString  = "PLACE_LOCATION"

    var php_result = "<?php
                       $php_inputString = '"+inputString+"';
                       echo getWeather_PHP($php_inputString);
                      ?>";
</script>
```

And the Error is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqbsP.png)

another error report I got is 
**Warning**: file_get_contents("+this_url+"): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/Index.php** on line **50**

Comment: Probably need an `echo` before the `getWeather_PHP`. The `return` sends the value back but you don't do anything with it in the PHP.

Comment: You are also missing a `$` in your `return $weather_data;`. Regarding the error in the browser console, I'm pretty sure you are missing some js files.

Comment: Oh forgot the type the echo here I do have that in my code

Comment: another report I got is 
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(&quot;+this_url+&quot;): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/Index.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />

Comment: Oh cool, so you found the error. Your url is incorrect. Maybe you should remove `$url = (string)$url;`.

Comment: @lbu You're going down a blind alley. The `(string)` casts are unnecessary, but aren't the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var php_result = "<?php
                   $php_inputString = '"+inputString+"';
                   echo getWeather_PHP($php_inputString);
                  ?>";
```

PHP is evaluated on the server, long before Javascript runs. The PHP interpreter outputs all content outside `<?php … ?>` tags directly, without interpreting it in any way.

From the perspective of PHP, `$php_inputstring` is set to the *literal* text `"+inputString+"`. This leads `getWeather_PHP()` to attempt to get the weather in the city `"+inputString+"`, which fails.

If you need the `getWeather_PHP()` function to be callable from Javascript, you will need to expose it as a separate AJAX endpoint. There is no way to interwork Javascript and PHP in the way you're attempting here.

Comment: thank you so so much for helping 
but just wondering if I can just ajax_post a JS variable ?
and get it in PHP?